What are the actual rules for final_suspend's awaiter in C++ coroutines?
In C++ coroutines, the promise type's final_suspend member function can return any arbitrary awaitable type, though commonly it's std::suspend_always which leaves the responsibility to someone else to destroy the coroutine, or std::suspend_never which automatically destroys the coroutine. The latter seems to be a special case, since normally it is not allowed to resume a coroutine that is at its final suspend point. In my testing though, it seems like this special behavior is not uniformly applied.
The crux of the issue is that an awaitable's await_suspend member function can have any of three different return types: if it returns void, the coroutine remains suspended. If it returns bool, the coroutine is resumed for false and remains suspended for true. If it returns a std::coroutine_handle, that coroutine gets resumed.
I've tested the behavior of all of those outcomes with the return value of final_suspend, and all three of MSVC, Clang, and GCC converge on this behavior for an awaitable where await_ready always returns false:

If final_suspend().await_suspend(handle) returns void, the coroutine remains suspended at its final suspend point as expected.
If final_suspend().await_suspend(handle) returns bool(true), the coroutine remains suspended at its final suspend point in this case too.
If final_suspend().await_suspend(handle) returns bool(false), interestingly the coroutine is automatically destroyed, as can be seen by the promise type's destructor being executed. This aligns with the behavior of std::suspend_never, and shows the decision can be made at runtime. Also interesting to note, await_resume is called before destroying the coroutine as well, even though its result is discarded.
If final_suspend().await_suspend(handle) returns another coroutine's handle, that coroutine is resumed as expected, and the current coroutine remains suspended at its final suspend point.
If final_suspend().await_suspend(handle) returns the same handle it is given, the program crashes!

Outcomes 1, 2, and 4 are as expected. Outcomes 3 and 5 are what interest me most - from a certain perspective, you'd think they would be treated the same, since in both cases they are trying to "resume" the completed coroutine, yet only outcome 3 seems to get special handling for automatically destroying the coroutine. This makes it a bit awkward to decide this at runtime when returning a coroutine handle, since instead you have to manually destroy the coroutine and then return a no-op coroutine handle, which is a tad more complex than simply returning false for the same effect, and might even make some use cases impossible due to having to return a type-erased handle.
My question is, where exactly are these specific outcomes described or mandated in the C++ standard? When I look, I can't find very much. The standard appears rather brief in its descriptions of coroutine behavior. The special behavior of final_suspend's awaitable seems like it'd be important to document, and I can't find it. I can find a statement that final_suspend and usage of its awaitable must be noexcept ("shall not be potentially-throwing"), but that's about it as far as special rules go from what I can find. What section am I missing? Why does returning the same handle that was passed in result in different behavior from returning false?

When await_suspend returns false, the coroutine is resumed. This results in control flowing off the end of the coroutine, which destroys the coroutine state.
When await_suspend returns a handle, resume() is called on that handle. This violates the precondition of resume(), so the behavior is undefined.

Wow, that's a very subtle difference between saying the coroutine is resumed versus saying resume is invoked which resumes the coroutine. Given that those sentences are so close together you'd think they were intended to be interpreted in the same way. Are we sure this is the definitive difference? Perhaps I'm just not used to how terse the standard can be.

What about the precondition is being violated? Because the coroutine isn't considered suspended until after await_suspend returns?

@JosephGarvin The precondition violation is on the resume member function generally, whether you use it directly or the standard says the compiler uses it. The standard also sometimes says the compiler must resume a coroutine without using the resume member function, which is the difference here. The coroutine is already fully suspended by the time await_suspend is called.
